# Display and save only hours in int

Tags: java, time

How to display only hours and using int variable? I mean print time like 20:30:44 PM,  I want to store only hours, mean 20 in int variable. how to do that?

Can anybody tell me the code if you know, thanks?

Comment: If you parse your timestamp into a Date object you can use date.getHours().

Comment: Could you edit this question to add some detail? Do you have some existing code where this 20:30:44 PM value is stored in a variable? What data type is it?

Comment: Yes sure Im getting null pointer  exception  problem can u solve this                 package com.time;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DefaultTime {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Date date = null;
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  if (c != null) {
   c.setTime(date);
   int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   System.out.println(hour);
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

Try using Calendar's [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method like:

```
 Calendar c = ..
 c.setTime(...);//if you have time in long coming from somewhere else
 int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: Calendar will hold your date time with it and from date time it will give you hour in 24 hour format.

Comment: SMA can u tell me the code in brief its not working when use your logic

Comment: Can you update the code with which you tried and that is not working?

Comment: Yeah u tried but it says null pointer excepts I put condition it shows again null pointer exception in variable c.get

Comment: Do you have any code that throws Null pointer exception? can you update that in question above?

Comment: Yes sure Im getting null pointer exception problem can u solve this  public class DefaultTime { public static void main(String args[]) { Date date = null; Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); if (c != null) { c.setTime(date); int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); System.out.println(hour); } }

Comment: Thats because your date object is null. try initializing Date to like `Date date = new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to parse time from String I recommend these solutions:

```
String time = "20:30:44 PM"; // this is your input string
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa");

try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(time);

    // this is the uglier solution
    System.out.println("The hour is: "+date.getHours());

    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(date);

    // this is nicer solution
    System.out.println("The hour is: "+gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't parse string! "+e.getMessage());
}
```

`date.getHours()` and `gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` return `int`, in this example I printed it out without creating variable.

You can, of course, use regular expression to find out hour in your string but above solutions should do the trick. You can learn more about `SimpleDateFormat` and available patterns [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). I hope I helped you a bit.

*EDIT*: In his comment autor noted, that date isn't static (like in String) but dynamic:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
System.out.println("The hour is: "+hour);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks its working but My problem is time should be dynamic and hour should store in int variable can u tell me that code please

Comment: @RameshKumar here, I edited my post, if you have problems let me know, we will solve it.