# Store hours value in into variable

Tags: java

My problem time 20:34:54 pm time should dynamic changes  so I want only hour 20 to store it in into int variable 
How to solve it any body explain in briefly in coding  please
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you have a `Date` or a `String`? Have you tried searching for simliar questions here or on google?

Comment: Same has been asked today and was asnwered by me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796710/display-and-save-only-hours-in-int/28796738)

Comment: briefly: convert to seconds from midnight then calculate the hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28797490/4618338).

If you try to parse time from String I recommend these solutions:

```
String time = "20:30:44 PM"; // this is your input string
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa");

try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(time);

    // this is the uglier solution
    System.out.println("The hour is: "+date.getHours());

    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(date);

    // this is nicer solution
    System.out.println("The hour is: "+gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't parse string! "+e.getMessage());
}
```

`date.getHours()` and `gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` return `int`, in this example I printed it out without creating variable.

You can, of course, use regular expression to find out hour in your string but above solutions should do the trick. You can learn more about `SimpleDateFormat` and available patterns [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). I hope I helped you a bit.

*EDIT*: getting hour not from string but actuall date:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
System.out.println("The hour is: "+hour);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have it stored as a String, you can simply do:

```
String[] splitTime = time.split(":");
int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitTime[0]);
```

The first line splits the String at the ':' character, and the second one parses the String "20" into an integer.

If it's stored as something else, such as some sort of time container object, you'll have to specify because the process will be different.